# Unable to use DirectX.Capture library

Tags: c#, directx

I am unable to use [DirectX.Capture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3566/DirectX-Capture-Class-Library) library because the following code from the example gave me errors:

```
Capture capture = new Capture(
    Filters.VideoInputDevices[0],
    Filters.AudioInputDevices[0]);

capture.Start();

capture.Stop();
```

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
> property 'DirectX.Capture.Filters.AudioInputDevices'
>
> An object
> reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property
> 'DirectX.Capture.Filters.VideoInputDevices'

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The message is saying that the member `AudioInputDevices` and the member `VideoInputDevices` are not declared as `static` in the type `DirectX.Capture.Filters`, but you are using them as if they were `static`.

To reference a member that's not `static`, you need to instantiate that type, by calling the constructor (directly, or indirectly via some kind of factory method) of that type (`DirectX.Capture.Filters`).

In other words, you need something like this:

```
var filters = new DirectX.Capture.Filters(...);
var capture = new Capture(filters.VideoInputDevices[0], filters.AudioInputDevices[0]);
```